# c++ set char array length with variable

Tags: arrays, char, initialization

Why can I set the length of a char array with

```
const int i=10;
char temp[i];
```

But not with

```
const int i=anotherInt;
char temp[i];
```

?

Comment: Probably because anotherInt isn't a compile-time constant.

Comment: Ok. But who cares if i stays constant? I think the compiler wants to make sure that the size of the i doesn't change in order to make the array size init safe. Why does it have to know the size before compilation?